# Iterate over cursor with offset

Tags: mongodb, cursor

I have got following data:

```
{ _id: "aaa" }
{ _id: "aab" }
{ _id: "aav" }
{ _id: "baa" }
{ _id: "bac" }
{ _id: "bad" }
```

I want to get my cursor to, lets say, documents starting on `b` and iterate to the end.

Pseudocode

```
cursor.offset(_id: "b").each{ |doc| puts doc }
#=> { _id: "baa" }
#=> { _id: "bac" }
#=> { _id: "bad" }
```

As far as MongoDB stores indexes in B-Tree it should be possible somehow :)

Comment: from which query you got the cursor?

Comment: never mind, it was easy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just search for all documents >= "b":

```
db.collection.find( { _id: { $gte: "b" } } );
```

And then iterate over the result set.

Answer (score 1):

@Derick answer is great. Yet another alternative is using `$regex`.

```
db.collection.find({_id: {$regex: "^b"}})
```

**Note:** `$regex` reduce down into `$gte` / `$lte` query if `^` is used.

Comment: That works, but a regex search is not as fast as a normal $gte

Comment: @Derick Yup, there is a slight overhead using `$regex` query even with '^' (assuming case sensitive matching) compared to normal `$gte` query. Such regex queries are itself reduced to `$gte` queries.